# Springdoc PropertyCustomizer is not inwoked for all Types

Tags: java, spring, springdoc, customizer

In our spring project we have over hundred of schemas I have a task to set all types in schemas annotated with @Nonnull to required so they appear is required (with a *) in Swagger. I've overridden the method customize from springdoc's PropertyCustomizer the following way:

```
@Override
public Schema customize(Schema property, AnnotatedType type) {

    Annotation[] ctxAnnotations = type.getCtxAnnotations();
    if (ctxAnnotations == null) {
        return property;
    }

    boolean isNonnull = Arrays.stream(ctxAnnotations)
            .anyMatch(annotation -> annotation.annotationType().equals(Nonnull.class));

    if (isNonnull) {
        if (type.getParent().getRequired() == null) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(type.getPropertyName());
            type.getParent().setRequired(list);
        } else {
            type.getParent().getRequired().add(type.getPropertyName());
        }
    }
    return property;
}
```

It works succesfully for most of the types but for some of them the method customize seems not be inwoked at all. Giving an example we have a class TripListingOgItem:

```
@Value
@Builder
public class TripListingOgItem {

@Nonnull String name;

@Nullable String image;

@Nonnull String url;

}
```

So according to it both name and url should appear as required in swagger but only name does. I even tried to print all the types with their parents and bool if isNonnull for which the method is inwoked and url was nowhere to be found:

```
        System.out.println(
                "\nParent: " + type.getParent().getName() +
                "\nType: " + type.getPropertyName() +
                "\nIsNonnull: " + isNonnull
);
```

I have no idea why the method does not get inwoked for some types. The class with this method is being registered with a simple bean in a configuration class:

```
@Bean
public PropertyCustomizer propertyCustomizer() {
    return new PropertyCustomizer();
}
```

I am using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I know I can simply annotate all the types with schema(required=true) but since it would be a long process and require constant maintenance we consider that a last resort solution. Thanks anyone in advance and have a nice day!